# (Revisted) Invertibility is necessary and sufficient for bijectivity...

Tags: real-analysis, elementary-set-theory, functions, function-and-relation-composition

Let $f:X\rightarrow Y$ be non-surjective (not onto), and let $g:Y\rightarrow Z$ be non-injective (not $1-1$). Now, construct the composition $g\circ f$ such that it's a bijection.

---

My approach was this: Let $f$ be $x^2$, and let $g$ be $x^2$, thus $g\circ f$ is $x^4$, which has an inverse, namely $\sqrt[4]{x}$, and since invertability is necessary and sufficient for bijectivity, then the desired construction is complete.

---

Here is my second approach: Let $f$ be defined as $f(x)=\sqrt{x}$, where $f:\mathbb{R_{\geq 0}}\rightarrow \mathbb{R}$, and let $g$ be defined as $g(x)=x^2$, where $g:\mathbb{R}\rightarrow \mathbb{R_{\geq 0}}$, so $(g\circ f)(x)=x$, which clearly is invertible and therefore bijective, and thus the desired construction has been completed; *quod erat demonstrandum*. Right?

Comment: It's of critical importance that you state the domains and ranges of your functions.

Comment: They are both over $\mathbb{R}$. Is that what you mean?

Comment: Well, they aren't defined on all of $\mathbb{R}$.

Comment: @ZachL. What about now?

Comment: You still haven't stated the domains and ranges of your functions. In particular, you **must** state what $X,Y,Z$ are in your example.

Comment: With the most recent edit, I say $X=Y=Z=\mathbb{R}$, yeah?

Comment: Nope. That doesn't work, as $\sqrt[4]x$ isn't defined on all of $\Bbb R$.

Comment: OK, so I'm trying to find functions such that $f:\mathbb{R} \rightarrow \mathbb{R_{\geq 0}}$ and $g:\mathbb{R_{\geq 0}}\rightarrow \mathbb{R}$, yeah?

Comment: Indeed, your second approach works perfectly! I also recommend taking a glance through the answers below (particularly Zach L.'s, as he aptly demonstrates just why the domain and codomain need to be specified.

Answer (score 3):

Your second approach looks good!

Here is a very simple example. Let $X = Z = \{1\}$ and $Y = \{1,2\}$. Let $f(1) = 1$ and $g(1) = g(2) = 1$. When trying to think of injectivity/surjectivity examples, I've always found it's easier to work with small finite sets.

Here is an example illustrating why, when discussing injectivity and surjectivity, you have to think carefully about domain and range.

- $f:\mathbb{R} \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ defined by $f(x) = x^2$. It's
  not surjective (it misses $-1$), and it's not injective, since $f(1)
     = f(-1)$.
- $g:\mathbb{R} \rightarrow \mathbb{R}_{\geq 0}$ defined by $g(x) =
     x^2$. It's not injective, since $g(-1) = g(1)$. (Note that these
  values are actually in the range of $g$, so this is well defined.) But
  $g$ is surjective! Its range is all positive reals, and every
  positive real has a square root.
- $h:\mathbb{R}_{\geq 0} \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ defined by $h(x) =
     x^2$. It's now injective, since every positive real has a unique
  positive root, but not surjective, since we have included $-1$ to the
  range.
- $j:\mathbb{R}_{\geq 0} \rightarrow \mathbb{R}_{\geq 0}$ defined by
  $j(x) = x^2$. This function is now both injective and surjective.

Now observe that every possibility of failure/success of injectivity/surjectivity is exhibited in this list of four functions, but *all four were defined using the same formula*. All that distinguishing these functions is the domain and range.

Comment: +1: I made a few small edits of punctuation and grammar, but you really illustrated the point well!

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you have $\operatorname{f},\operatorname{g}: \mathbb{R} \to \mathbb{R}$, your example does not work.

You have $\operatorname{f}(x) = x^2$ and $\operatorname{g}(x) = x^2$. It follows that the composite function $\operatorname{g}\circ\operatorname{f}$ is given by $(\operatorname{g}\circ\operatorname{f})(x) = (x^2)^2 \equiv x^4$. This function *is not* bijective since $x^4 \ge 0$ for all $x$. A function must take all values, i.e. be surjective, in order to be bijective.

Note that $x \mapsto x^4$ is not injective. We have $(-1)^4 = 1$ *and* $(+1)^4 = 1$. Two values, $x = \pm1$ are sent to the same value. Furthermore, notice that invertibility is not equivalent to bijectivity. The function $\operatorname{h} : \mathbb{R} \to \mathbb{R}$ given by $\operatorname{h}(x) = \operatorname{e}^x$ is invertible, $\operatorname{h}^{-1}(x) = \ln x$, but it is not bijective. What value of $x$ gives $\operatorname{e}^x = -1$? It is not surjective and so not bijective. However, $\operatorname{h} : \mathbb{R} \to \mathbb{R}^+$ *is* bijective.  Ivertibilty makes a function bijective onto its image.

Comment: Without specifying the domains/ranges used, there's no way to determine injectivity or surjectivity.

Comment: @CameronBuie I'm trying to be pragmatic. The OP's use of the variable $x$ makes it pretty clear that s/he has the real numbers in mind as the domain. This is most likely the range given the first example of $\operatorname{f}(x) = \frac{1}{x}$. The OP has typed the expressions $x^2$, $\tfrac{1}{x}$ and $\tfrac{1}{x^2}$. It's a space with a multiplicative structure, a multiplicative identity and a multiplicative inverse, and the letter $x$ is used as a variable. It's most probably the real numbers, or perhaps the non-zero reals.

Answer (score 0):

Try this: $X=Z=\mathbb N_0$, $Y=\mathbb Z$, $f(x)=x$, $g(x)=|x|$.

Answer (score 0):

Consider $f\colon \mathbb{R}\to\mathbb{R}$ defined by $f(x)=\arctan x$. Now define
$$
g(x)=
\begin{cases}
\tan x & \text{if $x\notin X$}\\
0 & \text{if $x\in X$}
\end{cases}
$$
where $X$ is the set of numbers of the form $(2k+1)\pi/2$ for all integers $k$.

Of course $f$ is not surjective and $g$ is not injective, but $g\circ f$ is the identity, which of course is bijective.

---

Your argument is flawed: you're using $g=f$; $f$, as a map from $\mathbb{R}$ to $\mathbb{R}$ is not injective.

---

If $X$, $Y$ and $Z$ are arbitrary, you can take $X=\{0\}$, $Y=\{1,2\}$ and $Z=\{3\}$; define $f(0)=1$, $g(1)=3=g(2)$. The composition $g\circ f$ is the unique map from $X$ to $Z$ which, of course, is bijective.